# How to make UserControls in HTML pages?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a web application that uses pure HTML and jquery.

I have a Scenario to use Usercontrol type controls inside my HTML pages.
Means, reuse that user control in many html pages. (like .ascx from asp.net pages).

For e.g. Below div is User-Control.

```
  <div id="divdtTimeSetting">
     <table class="table">
       <tr>
       <td colspan="2" class="tdColor">
      <input type="button" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 95%" class="closeProperty" />
      </td>
       </tr>
         <tr>
          td colspan="2" class="tdColor" align="center" style="background-color: lightgray">Test1</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="tdColor" style="width: 50%">フォーカスを失った時</td>
            <td class="tdColor">
            <input type="button" value="---" style="width: 20px; margin-left: 85%" /></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
       <td colspan="2" class="tdColor" align="center" style="background-color: lightgray">Test2</td>
 </tr> </table></div>
```

I am thinking to make XML file of that bunch of controls means that User-control but again how to generate XML file which has form element details including all attributes or properties which has defined for respective control?

P.S. I am using only HTML and Jquery.

Any pointers for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from [here.](https://github.com/Jxck/html2json).

Using html2json and back json2html.